# How to count the nodes which have exactly one child by using Erlang?

Tags: erlang, binary-search-tree

I have some problem when trying to find the node that has exactly one child, but the function doesn't return the right number (keep going return 0)

This is my code:

```
helper(Tree, Acc) ->
    case Tree of
    {Value, Left, Right} ->
     if
         {Value, Left, empty} -> helper(Left, Acc +1);
         {Value, empty, Right} -> helper(Right, Acc +1);
         {Value, Left, Right} -> helper(Left, Acc),
         helper(Right, Acc);
         true -> Acc
     end
    end.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

1. The `if` is unnecessary in your code, you can (and should) pattern-match directly on the `case` statement.
2. You're not preserving the result of calling `helper(Left, Acc)` when calling `heper(Right, Acc)` in the third clause of your `if`/`case`.

I didn't test it, but I think your code should work if you write it like this:

```erlang
helper(Tree, Acc) ->
    case Tree of
         {Value, Left, empty} -> helper(Left, Acc +1);
         {Value, empty, Right} -> helper(Right, Acc +1);
         {Value, Left, Right} -> helper(Right, helper(Left, Acc));
         _ -> Acc
    end.
```

As a matter of fact, you don't even need the `case` statement at all…

```erlang
helper({Value, Left, empty}, Acc) -> helper(Left, Acc + 1);
helper({Value, empty, Right}, Acc) -> helper(Right, Acc + 1);
helper({Value, Left, Right}, Acc) -> helper(Right, helper(Left, Acc));
helper(_, Acc) -> Acc.
```

And, if you try to compile this, Erlang will promptly tell you that `Value` is unused everywhere. So, it would be better to write…

```erlang
helper({_, Left, empty}, Acc) -> helper(Left, Acc + 1);
helper({_, empty, Right}, Acc) -> helper(Right, Acc + 1);
helper({_, Left, Right}, Acc) -> helper(Right, helper(Left, Acc));
helper(_, Acc) -> Acc.
```

But, to be fair… I think you are still missing a clause for `{_, empty, empty}`. Otherwise, you'll count that as a node with exactly one child when it actually has none…

```erlang
helper({_, empty, empty}, Acc) -> Acc;
helper({_, Left, empty}, Acc) -> helper(Left, Acc + 1);
helper({_, empty, Right}, Acc) -> helper(Right, Acc + 1);
helper({_, Left, Right}, Acc) -> helper(Right, helper(Left, Acc));
helper(_, Acc) -> Acc.
```